# How do i connect to an ethereum node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm new to Ethereum and i just setup my first Node. Basically i needed a way to query the Ethereum blockchain to retrieve data, so i decided to setup a light node on a VPS using Geth.

Everything seems to work, the node is up, but now what i don't understand is what i need to do in order to query the node and get Ethereum data. For example, when i use Web3JS or Web3py, what url do i need to set on my provider, in order to access my own node? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your node run a json rpc api.

You can connect either through http or ws. By default, it only listens on localhost :

```
- HTTP : http://localhost:8545
- WebSockets : ws://localhost:8546
```

You can specify the interface you wish to listen on.

For http, start geth with `--http.addr 0.0.0.0` and connect with

```js
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(`http://{IP}:8545/`));
```

For ws, start geth with `--ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0` and connect with

```js
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(`ws://{IP}:8546/`));
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Is it possible that i need to do something else? Because whatever i try, when i try to access it from outside the vps, i always get a False when i print w3.isConnected(), while if i do it from inside the vps it returns True

Comment: Check if firewall is accepting external connections on port `8545` and `8546`

Comment: So if i do telnet 8545 from the Vps it connects, if i do telnet <MY-IP> 8545 it doesn't connect, so i think that's the problem; is there any way i can make it accept the connection?